# Generating interesting/useful features from existing useless features

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, interaction, feature-engineering

I am new to ML and trying to work on a binary classification problem.

I came to know that one of the main factors for success of ML is feature engineering. I am here to seek some inspiration/help from experienced folks here on how to generate creative/interesting features based on existing features. My dataset is given below

[image]

In my dataset, I have already created some new features based on existing date columns (existing date columns are not shown in screenshot. Only derived date columns are shown here). Refer below

`date_diff_1` - indicates the time taken by company to respond to customer in days.

`date_diff_2` - indicates the time taken by customer to book his 1st PO after the deal is made.

`date_diff_3` - indicates the time taken by customer to hit 1000$ revenue

Additionally, `Division` and `category-Division` variables are correlated. So, I plan to remove the highly cardinal column `category-Division`.

How does one approach feature engineering in scenarios like this? what are some of the usual/typical practice that data scientists follow to create interesting features to uncover hidden info (from the data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Arthur's answer is quite valuable here, but I think some more detail can be added.

Let's keep in mind that feature engineering is not the same as data collection. You should absolutely collect more data and more variables/information if you can. However, at the stage of feature engineering, we're assuming you already have all the raw data you could get.

During feature engineering, your job is to select, transform and combine these raw data variables in ways that are helpful to the model.

The process that Arthur outlines is absolutely correct - to engineer good features, you need to have some subject matter input (someone who understands exactly what each variable means, how it was gathered etc.) . This way, you can combine this expertise with some creativity to find new ways of representing the data.

Let's move away from these somewhat abstract definitions, and let me give you some potential ideas for features.

Most fundamental thing to keep in mind: It's a huge range of potential here. **As long as you're not leaking data,** **you can try literally whatever you can think of**. There are no boundaries. If you have an idea that you think makes sense in the context of the problem, try it!

Some ideas I had, given your dataset (adjust these to your understanding of the data, as I might not fully know your situation):

1. Average booking QTY of the customer (up until a point in time, remember - no data leaking from the future, don't average across the whole dataset, only the data you would've had at that point)
2. Average size of order or price of item of the customer (up until a point in time, remember - no data leaking from the future, don't average across the whole dataset, only the data you would've had at that point. As I hope you realize, this comment applies to ALL the features I mention, and all features you can think of.)
3. Number of orders this customer has made with you
4. With your date_diff variables, you could again take averages (like average time to respond to this customer etc., rather than just the most recent response time)
5. You could take standard deviations of these date_diff variables (to see how consistent it is over time)
6. If you have the data for it, you could look at average of actual revenue realized vs. your "revenue expected" column ("On average, the realized revenue is x% of expected revenue, for this customer/category)
7. You could look at any of the above variables and calculate them only for the customers within a certain category, and then compare your given customer to all other customers in that category (so for example, look at the number of orders customer X, in category Z, has made with you COMPARED to the average number of orders ALL customers in category Z have made with you. You could express this number as a percentile).

I think this gives some pointers and inspiration!

Comment: thanks @Vladimir Belik. Your suggestions are always helpful. Upvoted

Comment: For your 6th point on looking at average of actual revenue realized, do you think that can be qualified as data leakage? Meaning, my label is inferred based on difference between `target` and `booked` qty. If difference > 50%, label=0, otherwise label=1. So, with amount of booked quantities and price of each unit, I can know the revenue realized (as of that time point). So, in that case if I compute actual revenue realized, that may be qualified as data leakage. Right?

Comment: Meaning if 50% expected (target) order qty is booked, we consider it as label 1. Which is nothing but, if 50% of expected revenue is realized, it is label 1. 50% of orders equals 50% of expected revenue. So, am I right to think and be alert that 6th point will qualify as data leakage?

Comment: @TheGreat It would only be data leakage if you are using "realized revenue" from the future, or from data that you model "shouldn't have seen yet". If you treat it as "among all the data we have see so far, what is the realized revenue vs. expected revenue for this customer?", that would be fine. If you are doing cross validation though, you would need to be very careful about the way you do this between folds (it would prob have to be recalculated for each fold).

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Belik - I have related similar question here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567448/how-to-capture-trend-in-time-series-price-data     Will you be able to help?

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

- Year, month, hour etc. to capture time effects
- Details about the customer (country of residence, number of past purchases, etc.)
- Details about the product (product classification)

Process for feature engineering:

- Talk to subject matter experts
- Research similar models in the literature
- Creativity and reflection (easy, right? ;))

Comment: thanks, upvoted for the help

Comment: but the ideas that you suggest may result in data leakage?

Comment: I mean `no of past purchases` etc.

Comment: I don't think so, as long as you calculate the value for every order only using information that was available at the time the order was placed.  You can consider stratifying your cross-validation folds and train-test split in time.